# GKE failed to ensure load balancer: External IP is pending

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am running guestbook example on a Google Container Engine installation (tutorial): https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/

In creating frontend service, I got an error:
Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer (failed to create forwarding rule for load balancer)

```
NAME       TYPE                CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP            PORT(S)        AGE
frontend   LoadBalancer   X.X.X.X              <pending>           80:31463/TCP.     11m
```

External IP is pending.

Error in Kubernetes Engine > Services:

```
Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: failed to create forwarding rule for load balancer (a5ec51ef24a914395ac55474dbf1a76b(default/frontend)): googleapi: Error 412: Constraint constraints/compute.restrictLoadBalancerCreationForTypes violated for projects/test-03-10-05-2020. Forwarding Rule projects/test-03-10-05-2020/regions/us-east1/forwardingRules/a5ec51ef24a914395ac55474dbf1a76b of type EXTERNAL_NETWORK_TCP_UDP is not allowed., conditionNotMet
```

Comment: Could you please share the link or the deployment/service spec please?

Comment: link to tutorial: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/

Comment: Question, did you reserve an ip for your loadbalancer? The reason I am asking is if that is the case, please make sure IP address is in the same region as cluster created.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GCP on free mode, there is a restriction for using external IP at same time. AFAIK it could be 5 at most. It could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue is resolved using another mode for GCP